# Executing a command using Net::SSH

Tags: ruby, networking, ssh

According to the local cop (rubocop), my method has too many lines.

```
lib/awesomelibrary/tunnelable.rb:4:5: C: Method has too many lines. [17/10]
    def tunnel_run(cmd) ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Below is the method. How do I refactor it?

```
module AwesomeLibrary
  # Gives object the ability to execute bash commands on itself via ssh                                          
  module Tunnelable
    def tunnel_run(cmd)
      retries = 0
      code = nil
      Net::SSH.start(@tunnel_ip, @tunnel_username, keys: @tunnel_key_name, verify_host_key: false) do |ssh|
        the_channel = ssh.open_channel do |channel|
          channel.exec cmd do |ch, success|
            raise "could not execute command" unless success
            ch.on_data { |_c, data| print data }
            ch.on_extended_data { |_c, _type, data| print data }
            ch.on_request("exit-status") { |_ch, data| code = data.read_long }
          end
        end
        the_channel.wait
      end
      abort "#{cmd} returned #{code} !!" if code != 0
    rescue Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
      puts "Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout"
      retry if (retries += 1) < 3
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using this is the library: [Net::SSH 4.x](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh).

Comment: You don't necessary _need_ to refactor anything. Sure, it could probably be made prettier by one metric or another, but.. eh'. I'd be more concerned that it'll retry forever, since `retry` will start the method over, setting `retries = 0` each time...

Comment: As much as I hate to be "that guy", letting a script tell you that your method has too many lines is a terrible reason to refactor. Does it work? Does it make sense? Is it testable? *Those* are the important questions, not "how many lines does it have?".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your method does not have too many lines, but the line calling Net::SSH.start is too long.

My terminals and text editors are 80 characters wide, so I would split the long line into 2 lines

```
      Net::SSH.start(@tunnel_ip, @tunnel_username, keys: @tunnel_key_name,
                     verify_host_key: false) do |ssh|
```

If you must reduce the number of lines, you can move some lines into new methods. The extra method calls will make spaghetti of the control flow, so the code will be difficult to read and understand, but it might satisfy your cop.

```
    def tunnel_run(cmd)
        retries = 0
        code = tunnel_run_command(cmd)
        abort ... if code != 0
    rescue Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
        ...
    end

    private
    def tunnel_run_command(cmd)
        code = nil
        Net::SSH.start(...) do |ssh|
            the_channel = ssh.open_channel do |channel|
                channel.exec do |ch, success|
                    code = tunnel_run_channel(ch, success)
                end
            end
            the_channel.wait
        end
        code
    end

    def tunnel_run_channel(ch, success)
        code = nil
        raise ... unless success
        ch.on_data { ... }
        ch.on_extended_data { ... }
        ch.on_request("exit-status") { ... }
        code
    end
```

Beware that the private methods `tunnel_run_command` and `tunnel_run_channel` will pollute the method namespace in all objects that extend Tunnelable.  Privacy in Ruby is by object, so the object inherits the private methods from Tunnelable, and Ruby allows the object to call those methods.

The names `tunnel_run_command` and `tunnel_run_channel` must not conflict with other methods of the object.